# std::enable_if and template alias, prevent user from filling in std::enable_if parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using template aliases like so:

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
using vec2 = std::pair<T, T>;

template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
using vec3 = std::tuple<T, T, T>;
```

The problem is anyone can subvert this by doing `vec2<int, any_type>`. How do I prevent this?

Comment: implemenetation details shouldn't be public... hide it!

Comment: Murphy, Machiavelli, etc. Anyone can subvert this with `std::pair<int, int>` already, no matter how clever your SFINAE magic is.

Comment: Add a comment above it saying `// Please don't manually specify the second template parameter; that'll break things.`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not expand the `std::enable_if` at the `using` decl rather than the template argument list ([like this](http://ideone.com/8jwtNN))? Wouldn't be the first time I misread a question, but just wondering.

Comment: I'm not sure if `enable_if` is the right tool for this. I think it should mostly be used to remove function templates from overload sets, not to prevent class template specializations. It would seem nicer to just have a static assertion fire if the user misuses a class template.

Comment: @WhozCraig That makes it impossible to deduce `T` when you have a function template taking a `vec2<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a helper alias.

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
using vec2_impl = std::pair<T, T>;

template <typename T>
using vec2 = vec2_impl<T>;
```

Now, the name `vec2` can not be used in any way to produce a `std::pair<int, int>` type.

That said, as noted in the comments, this does not prevent anyone from using that type some other way, possibly by using `std::pair<int, int>` directly, possibly by writing `vec2_impl<int, void>`, but depending on what you want to use this for, it may be good enough.

Also, if you're using a template function declared like so:

```
template <typename T> void f(vec2<T>);
```

you don't need to do any additional work: the caller already has absolutely no way to pass any `std::pair<int, int>` or `vec2<int, void>` type. `T` can be deduced as `int`, but the following substition already fails even without having to use any helper alias.